# confused in a macro definition

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sicp, lazy-sequences

I want to implement the lazy stream in SICP section 3.5.1

Firstly, I defined this two functions

```
(defmacro delay (form)
  `(lambda () ,form))

(defun force (form)
  (when form
    (funcall form)))
```

When we called:

```
(force (delay '(+ 1 2)))
;;=> (+ 1 2)

(force (delay (+ 1 2)))
;;=> 3
```

So that's worked. Then I go on defining `stream-cons', but this time there
seems to be two ways:

```
(defmacro stream-cons (a b)
  `(cons ,a ,(delay b)))

(defmacro stream-cons (a b)
  `(cons ,a (delay ,b)))
```

I don't think they are different, but I am wrong! The first edition, which
is a wrong edition, when called:

```
(force (cdr (stream-cons 'a (progn (print "hello") 2))))
;;=> (PROGN (PRINT "hello") 2)

(macroexpand '(stream-cons 'a (progn (print "hello") 2)))
;;=> (CONS 'A #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN STREAM-CONS) {25ABB3A5}>)
```

and the second edition, which is right, when called:

```
(force (cdr (stream-cons 'a (progn (print "hello") 2))))
;; 
;; "hello" 
;; => 2

(macroexpand '(stream-cons 'a (progn (print "hello") 2)))
;;=> (CONS 'A (DELAY (PROGN (PRINT "hello") 2)))
```

Now, I am very confused. Who can kindly help me to make clear the different
of the two? Thanks a lot!

My Environment: Windows 32bits, SBCL 1.1.4

Answer (score 7):

This is an important concept to understand about macros.

The thing is that `,(delay b)` is evaluated at macroexpansion time, i.e. the `lambda` is created in place and is wrapped over the **literal** value passed to it which is the list of symbols. So you get a constant function that always returns the same value - a list that happens to be your code.

You can picture it like this:

```
,(delay '(progn (print "hello") 2)) => (lambda () '(progn (print "hello") 2))
```

In the second variant `(delay ,b)`:

```
(delay ,'(progn (print "hello") 2)) => (delay (progn (print "hello") 2))
```

The catch here is that the arguments to macro calls are passed literally, without evaluation. So `delay` receives effectively a quoted list (`'(progn (print "hello") 2)`). What comma does is cancel the quote if they meet.